# IF Statement - may need re-writing

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, custom-list, validation

I am using an IF statement to allow both a-z and A-Z characters (shown below).

```
+(IF(OR((AND(CODE(MID([Field],1,1))>64, 
CODE(MID([Field],1,1))<91)),
(AND(CODE(MID([Field],1,1))>96,
CODE(MID([Field],1,1))<123))),1,0))
```

However, I'm not sure if this is the best way of writing this code (because when I nest this in another OR statement my validation code breaks down).

I'm also not sure why there should be an 'AND' in there or why the end bit is 
1,0 
and not 1,1 like the others?
can anyone either explain or provide a link to a site which explains the basics please?
thanks.

Comment: i think you need to explain what your trying todo? from what i can see it doesnt look like an if function but more like a logical operator function that is used in vb or excel! from what i can see its getting a value from the result set or 1 or 0. where exactly do you want the validation and how are you doing it? through code? or directly on a sharepoint list or in sharepoint desinger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it.

I went back to basics, started with validation for 1 character:
requiring - either a lower case letter or uppercase or blank.
Got that working, then built it up around that.

It highlighted the simple problem all along - it was the count at the end:

**it should have been =15 and not =18!**

I couldn't understand why four lines of code [for the letters] counted for '**1**' and two lines of code for [the numbers] counted as '**2**'.

entire code:

```
=IF(
```

LEN([Field])=0
    ,TRUE
    ,(IF(LEN([Field])=9
      ,IF((
+(IF(OR((AND(CODE(MID([Field],1,1))>64,
CODE(MID([Field],1,1))<91)),
(AND(CODE(MID([Field],1,1))>96,
CODE(MID([Field],1,1))<123))),1,0))
+(IF(OR((AND(CODE(MID([Field],2,1))>64,
CODE(MID([Field],2,1))<91)),
(AND(CODE(MID([Field],2,1))>96,
CODE(MID([Field],2,1))<123))),1,0))
+(CODE(MID([Field],3,1))>47)
+(CODE(MID([Field],3,1))<58)
+(CODE(MID([Field],4,1))>47)
+(CODE(MID([Field],4,1))<58)
+(CODE(MID([Field],5,1))>47)
+(CODE(MID([Field],5,1))<58)
+(CODE(MID([Field],6,1))>47)
+(CODE(MID([Field],6,1))<58)
+(CODE(MID([Field],7,1))>47)
+(CODE(MID([Field],7,1))<58)
+(CODE(MID([Field],8,1))>47)
+(CODE(MID([Field],8,1))<58)
+(IF(OR((AND(CODE(MID([Field],9,1))>64,
CODE(MID([Field],9,1))<91)),
(AND(CODE(MID([Field],9,1))>96,
CODE(MID([Field],9,1))<123))),1,0))
=15 
),TRUE,FALSE),FALSE)))

which basically is a national insurance number in this format:
aa123456c
or
AB123456C
or 
blank entry

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to use a regular expression in your front end

Something like this :

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server"
     ErrorMessage="TextBox1 value must be anything from a-z" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
     ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z]"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: ...I don't know. We are validating a column on a list, so it seems easier to add the validation to the actual column which users submit to. I wouldn't know where to write the expression above. And we may wish to re-use the validation on a future column elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure where and what you want... but if it's a textbox you are entering the values into, you could use this :

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch("^[a-zA-Z]", textBox1.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Non alphabetic character in text!");
        textBox1.Text.Remove(textBox1.Text.Length - 1);
    }
}
```

This code will fire every time a new character is entered into your textbox. If it's not an alphabetic character it will be removed.

Comment: Please edit your first answer instead of adding another one :)